# How to iterate data from two dates by using month and year

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table Sample with some fields

```
EmpCode=a,OffID=1, FromDate=2015-01-01, ToDate='2015-01-10'
EmpCode=a,OffID=2, FromDate=2015-01-11, ToDate='2015-01-20'
EmpCode=a,OffID=1, FromDate=2015-01-21, ToDate='2015-01-29'
EmpCode=a,OffID=1, FromDate=2015-01-30, ToDate='2015-02-02'
```

I have 2 dropdown list to select month and year.I want the count of offID in month=1 and year=2015. how can I get it. See last OffID todate is 2015-02-01

Comment: `Count` or `Sum` of `offID in month=1 year=2015`?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, Sorry..I need Count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you need count of `offID` for the each month and when that `offID` belongs to `1st` month for both `todate` and `fromdate` and also same for the year You can do something like this

```
 Select count(offiD) 
 FROM  tablename 
 WHERE (MONTH(todate) = 1 AND MONTH(fromDate) =1 ) 
 AND (YEAR(fromDate) = 2015 AND YEAR(todate) = 2015)
```

If you want to filter it for only one date then just remove the second date filter.

---

**Update**

You need to put the single quote in your query if you are going to check with `hardcoded` values

Your Query

```
  Select count(offiD) 
  FROM 
      Offdayallocation 
  WHERE  
    (MONTH(2015-01-10) = 1 AND MONTH(2015-01-01) =1 ) 
    AND (YEAR(2015-01-01)= 2015 AND YEAR(2015-01-10) = 2015) 
    and EmpCode='a'
```

Change the condition like this,

```
   (MONTH('2015-01-10') = 1 AND MONTH('2015-01-01') = 1 ) 
    AND (YEAR('2015-01-01')= 2015 AND YEAR('2015-01-10') = 2015)
    and EmpCode='a'
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Post your query ? What you have tried ? And if there is any error post that too.

Comment: ,Select count(offiD) 
 FROM  Offdayallocation 
 WHERE (MONTH(2015-01-10) = 1 AND MONTH(2015-01-01) =1 ) 
 AND (YEAR(2015-01-01)= 2015 AND YEAR(2015-01-10) = 2015) and EmpCode='a'

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check it and if it helps you please accept it as the answer so question can be closed.